# Create an array of a parents children in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, parent-child, displayobject

I am trying to create an array of a parent div's (`id="lol"`) children and them fetch them to change `display:none;` except for the child with `id="a"`. I've tried this but it doesn't work. How can I improve this to get it to work?

```
function myFunction() {

  var x = document.getElementById('a');

  var children = [].slice.call(document.getElementById('lol').getElementsByTagName('*'),0);
  var arrayLength = children.length;          

  for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    var name = children[i].getAttribute('id');
    var z = document.getElementById(name);
    z.style.display = 'none';
  }
  x.style.display = 'block';
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about 'doesn't work' ? It looks like this code is trying to hide the id property. Do you get back the array of child divs? Would be nice to see a little more context.

Comment: Did you mean children or descendants? You say "children", but your code looks like it fetches all descendants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If every child has an `id` attribute than it will work. Otherwise, some children might not have `id` attribute, in that case variable `z` will be `undefined` and accessing `style` property over `z` which is `undefined` will give error. Simple fix would be just handling `undefined` variable:

```
   if(z)      
       z.style.display = 'none';
```

Same goes with variable `x`, too.

Comment: Worked as a charm :) Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

How about using jQuery?

```
$('#lol').children(':not(#a)').hide();
```

If jQuery is not an option you can do this:

```
var lol = document.getElementById('lol');
var children = lol.querySelectorAll(':not(#a)');
for(var i=0;i<children.length;i++) {
    children[i].style.display = 'none';
}
```

Even more "low-level":

```
var lol = document.getElementById('lol');
var children = lol.childNodes;
for(var i=0;i<children.length;i++){
    if(children[i].id != 'a') {
        children[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction() {


  var children = [].slice.call(document.getElementById('lol').getElementsByTagName('*'),0);
  var arrayLength = children.length;          

  for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
   children[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
  document.getElementById('a').style.display = 'block';
}
```